# How to edit system catalogs in PostgreSQL 8.1?

Tags: postgresql

I found some solution by adding

> allow_system_table_mods = on

to PostgreSQL configuration file.

But on PostgreSQL this doesn't work.
I can't find any other method that gives me access to edit this `catalogs`.

Has someone an idea?

Comment: Editing the system catalog by hand is usually a **BAD** idea.  Perhaps if you explain why you want to do such a thing someone can give you safer suggestions?

Comment: I know about how BAD idea is it, but this is a one way to solve my problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917484/allow-postgres-user-to-only-list-his-own-database

Comment: Realy i need this, i will wait for some answers.

Comment: **Another `allow_system_table_mods = on` motivation: enabled/disable triggers** which is currently not elegantly possible without admin rights (even if I create a function in some admins schema and grant execute rights to some non-admin, it does not work): http://stackoverflow.com/a/6152343/1915920

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just installed PostgresSQL 8.1 from [source code](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v8.1.23/) and have no issue with editing system catalogs as superuser. It's determined by `rolcatupdate` property in [`pg_roles`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/view-pg-roles.html) system catalog:

> Role may update system catalogs directly. (Even a superuser may not do
>   this unless this column is true.)

You can check it by:

```
SELECT rolcatupdate FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname LIKE 'postgres';
 rolcatupdate 
--------------
 t
(1 row)
```

For other roles you have `false` value, so you could (probably you shouldn't doing this at all, so be careful) set to `true`:

```
UPDATE pg_roles SET rolcatupdate = true WHERE rolname LIKE 'roleName'
```

---

Second way (let's say you don't have any superuser accout after some accident) is to run PostgreSQL server in [single-user mode](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/app-postgres.html):

> When running a stand-alone server, the session user will be set to the
>   user with ID 1. This user does not actually have to exist, so a
>   stand-alone server can be used to manually recover from certain kinds
>   of accidental damage to the system catalogs. **Implicit superuser powers**
>   are granted to the user with ID 1 in stand-alone mode.

Comment: postgres=# SELECT rolcatupdate FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname LIKE 'postgres';
 rolcatupdate
--------------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=#
postgres=# alter table pg_catalog.pg_database rename to pg_database_catalog;
ERROR:  permission denied: "pg_database" is a system catalog

Comment: sorry this dont work ;-/

Comment: @Svisstack: [pg_database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/catalog-pg-database.html) is internal PostgreSQL catalog. You can modify/update some values like `datacl`, but you can't change its name.

Comment: ok, how i can grant full access to update postgresql catalog with change its name on version 8.1? this is possible? i must migrate to newest version?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such grant and you really shouldn't touch catalogs in such way. I'll check if that is possible "manually". Why do you need that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917484/allow-postgres-user-to-only-list-his-own-database

Comment: I see from answers in this question i can do it in other versions

Comment: It looks like `allow_system_table_mods` property was introduced in [Postgres 8.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/runtime-config-developer.html) as developer option.